# Find office COM object and release it properly

Tags: c#, com, windows-services, office-interop, rcw

I am using an Application which do word and excel automation but does not release the COM objects properly. I have no access to the source code, so I would like to release the COM objects myself in a Windows Service.

Can I identify if an excel or word COM object is no longer in use and release it properly?

Comment: yes ( or terminate, destroy, kill vaporize) I dont want to find the instances in Task Manager. The reason is, the mentioned application runs on a server with many customers and when all of them start to working with office, issues arise with the automation.

Comment: WEll, Office applications should not be running server-side, so that's certainly the place to start cleaning things up...! `Processes` can be used to identify all running instances of an Office application, but I don't think there's any way to know which are "in use" and which not. Certainly there's no way to release them "properly" if the software that invoked them hasn't done so. "Killing" Office applications is going to leave a lot of "junk" around that could eventually make them completely unstable. The software manufacturer of the tool you want to use should do this work.

Comment: I know that (Microsoft statement to this topic https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) But I thought there is a solution for that problem